# Wooden felt-lined tray with numbers

Tags: identify-this-game

It's a wooden felt-lined tray with twelve wooden toggles--for lack of a better term--across one of the long sides.  They are numbered one through twelve, and you can flip them up or down.  Same numbers on both sides of each.  Also has two dice. It appears that the dice are intended to be thrown into the tray, and then something is to be done with the wooden numbers. That's it.  Anyone?

Answer (score 10):

I believe you are looking for [Shut the Box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shut_the_Box).

[image: Shut The Box]